# Where exactly in Activity to query the SQLite database?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-adapter

Been fighting with app crashes. Time to ask for help...

I'm using SQLite for the first time. I'm trying to display a simple event log in a ListView.

The main activity shows the log in a small ListView. If you click on it, it launches another activity showing a full screen ListView. But I also get the problem returning from a Preferences screen. So the problem is in the main Activity.

The main Activity works fine on launching the app. But it crashes occasionally when returning from another Activity with: Unable to resume activity ... trying to requery an already closed cursor. I've tried all kinds of variations without a solution. In debugging, it seems it can't even get to the onResume?

Can someone please point out where (onStart, onResume, onRestart) each piece of DB code is supposed to go? Any clues?

I know this code is based on a deprecated technique. But I want to get that to work before worrying about creating Loaders.

Any help will be appreciated. I have...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ...{
    private ListView logView;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private DBAdapter dbAdapter;
    private Cursor cursor;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter logAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        ... 
    }
    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        dbAdapter = new DBAdapter(this);
        db = dbAdapter.getReadableDatabase();

        cursor = db.query("log", null, null, null, null, null, "_id ASC");
        startManagingCursor(cursor);
        Log.i(TAG, "cursor="+cursor.toString());

        String[] from = { "entry"}; 
        int[] to = { R.id.row_entry }; 
        logAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.log_row, cursor, from, to);
        logView.setAdapter(logAdapter);

        logAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();      
        logView.setSelection(logView.getCount()-1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: I would suggest learning how to build a ContentProvider and use Loaders. Way to involved to explain here, but the Android docs have pages on how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

tTry something like this:

in onResume() put

```
    if(db==null) db=dbAdapter.getReadableDatabase();
```

and in onPause()

```
    if(db!=null) { db.close; db=null; }
```

Also i think you should study this article in detail, it will give you insisting for this problem and every next app you will be building. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

it has a diagram of the activity lifecycle. This way you will know when is onResume,onPause called etc, and you will know where to put the code.

Same thing here but with more explanation i think: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html